# How to clear the image view in android in this scenario?

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, adapter

```
private static class ViewHolder {
     ImageView imageView;
     TextView region;
     TextView area;
     TextView id;
     TextView shop_name;
     public String imageURL;
     public Bitmap bitmap;
}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (arg1 == null) {
        arg1 = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.details, arg2, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        viewHolder.region = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        viewHolder.area = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        viewHolder.id = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        viewHolder.shop_name = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        arg1.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder)arg1.getTag();
    viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);
    ShopEntry entry = getItem(arg0);
    viewHolder.imageURL = entry.image_url;
    viewHolder.region.setText(entry.region);
    viewHolder.area.setText(entry.area);
    viewHolder.id.setText(entry.id);
    viewHolder.shop_name.setText(entry.shop_name);
    new DownloadAsyncTask().execute(viewHolder);
    return arg1;
}

private class DownloadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, ViewHolder> {   
    @Override
    protected ViewHolder doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //load image directly
        ViewHolder viewHolder = params[0];

        try {
            URL imageURL = new URL(viewHolder.imageURL);
            viewHolder.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("test", "Downloading Image Failed");
            viewHolder.bitmap = null;
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ViewHolder result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (result.bitmap == null) {
            result.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);
        } else {
            result.imageView.setImageBitmap(result.bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code , I have implemented async task on a list view custom adapter. The problem is , when the image reload, it is replaced the old image, instead of clearing old image then reload the new image, so the display order is not correct.

I have put

```
viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);
```

inside getview() adapter but it seems not work as expected , how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time your async task downloads the image it is possible that adapter recycle the view holder so therefore async task will be setting the wrong image to the view holder instance.

You need to take care that async task assign the bitmap to the valid view holder not the staled one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is the problem I have encountered. Would you mind provide some example / or approach to doing this?

Comment: e.g. In post execute, checking what condition and execute something?

Comment: I think that's right. You probably should add an AtomicBoolean to ViewHolder class, which indicates, if the view is awaiting for an image, and not reuse the view if the flag is true. And in post execute method you set the flag to false.

Comment: Yes and you should cache the images so that next time when you scroll up/down and go to download the same image that you downloaded earlier but view holder got staled at that time. You can use Volley library provided by Google which provides a good feature of caching the images on file system